# Why is there a problem with the Java Api search template provided by the elasticsearch official website?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

[This is website official provided Java api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/6.5/java-search-template.html#java-search-template)
    -

```
SearchResponse sr = new SearchTemplateRequestBuilder(client)
.setScript("template_gender")                 
.setScriptType(ScriptService.ScriptType.FILE) //this ScriptService.ScriptType.FILE
.setScriptParams(template_params)             
.setRequest(new SearchRequest())              
.get()                                        
.getResponse();
```

My code is the following:

```
SearchResponse response = new SearchTemplateRequestBuilder(client)
            .setScript("query_by_type")
            .setScriptType(ScriptService.ScriptType.FILE) //error (ScriptService not found ScriptType)
            .setScriptParams(scriptParams)
            .setRequest(new SearchRequest("bookrack").types("book"))
            .get().getResponse();
```

my elastisearch version is 6.5.2

Why is it different from the official website？
setScriptType()
setScriptType here can only be (ScriptType.INLINE) and (ScriptType.STORED)

Comment: Using the two parameters also reports an error,

Comment: use ScriptType.STORED  
error:Exception in thread "main" ResourceNotFoundException[unable to find script [query_by_type] in cluster state]

Comment: user ScriptType.INLINE
error:Exception in thread "main" UncategorizedExecutionException[Failed execution]; nested: IOException[Unrecognized token 'query_by_type': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@4efbdf43; line: 1, column: 39]];